# Invalid column name '''

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO #Prefix_PCAC_temp select rtrim(ltrim(replace(@str1,"'",null)))
```

in the above line it is showing error invalid column name '''.PLZ provide me any solution.

Comment: Why the single quote in your string?

Comment: Provide more code, how are you creating the temporary table? Also, you probably mean the following with your replace: `replace(@str1,'''','')`, assuming you're trying to remove single-quotes.

Comment: what is @str1, is it a column name?

Comment: @Aishvarya the better question: why the double quotes?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to prevent incorrect syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO #Prefix_PCAC_temp select rtrim(ltrim(replace(@str1,'''',null)))
```

However, if there is `'` symbol in your `@str1` variable, the value will become `NULL`. Most likely you want this:

```
INSERT INTO #Prefix_PCAC_temp select rtrim(ltrim(replace(@str1,'''','')))
```

The query above eliminates `'` symbols from `@str1` variable and inserts the value into the table

Comment: Correct. You can not use the double quotation marks for string literals.